# Euler's totient function - inequality on even numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Is there a theorem that says:

> If $n$ is even then: $$\varphi(n)\le\frac{n-1}{2},$$ where $\varphi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

If there isn't such a theorem, how would I show/prove that this is true?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know the formula $\varphi(2^km)=2^{k-1}\varphi(m)$ when $k\ge1$ and $m$ is odd?

Comment: $\varphi(2^n)=2^{n-1}>\frac{2^n-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the two comments you'd have:

**Case 1:** $n=2^k m, k\ge 1$, $m>1$ odd, then $$\phi(n)=\phi(2^k)\phi(m) = 2^{k-1} \phi(m)  \le 2^{k-1} (m-1) < 2^{k-1} m - \frac 12 = \frac{n-1}{ 2}$$

**Case 2:** If $m=1$ then $\phi(n)=2^{k-1} =\frac n2 > \frac{n-1}{2}$.